# Include configurable product price with simple product options price in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

Is it possible or any option to include  configurable price with simple product options price.

Ex - T-Shirt(configurable product) - price -$100
     with associated two simple products 
    Color(option)
     Red - $50
     Blue - $60

Now will there any option that configurable product price will show:
 $160 when choose Red and $150 when choose Blue.
 Is there any configurable price option setting or is default ?
My requirement is to create configurable products only so I can handle inventory of each associated products. And simple product options price will include configurable product price too.

Comment: You should use simple product with custom option. Create T-shirt as simple product with price $100, add custom option color with two value: Red-$50 and Blue-$60.

Comment: @MageX In that case inventory wouldn't be control for every option.

Comment: @MageX Is there any solution so configurable product price + associated simple product option price will display?